# Only Draw Geometric Objects Above 8th Parallel North

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapnik

I have many geometric objects (in both SRID:4326 - the_geom - and SRID:3857 - the_web_geom - in PostGIS extension tables of PostgreSQL), including country boundaries, for the country of Ghana and I want to make a hard cut-off of [the 8th parallel north latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8th_parallel_north) - i.e. I only want to draw the_web_geom (SRID:3857) object if it falls above this line.

Is there a way in either Mapnik, by adjusting the extent property of the layer, or by amending the PostgreSQL query to only draw the geometric features that fall above this line of latitude? I believe one solution, for the point objects, would be `...WHERE ST_Y(the_geom) > 8.0`, but not sure if this is the best approach or how this would work with polygon objects.

Comment: How would you like to draw a polygon that crosses 8°N? Shall it be cut at the latitude, or left out completely?

Comment: Cut at the latitude.

Comment: This requires ST_Intersection with a polygon between 8°/12°N. The Mapnik extent only draws complete objects or nothing.

Comment: Is there an easier way to creating this polygon than just iterating over a range of decimals between the left- and right-most points in Ghana on the 8th and 12th parallels?

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way to do this - there is probably a faster way - is with `ST_Difference` against a constructed mask polygon:

```
SELECT
ST_Difference(ST_Transform(the_web_geom, 4326),
              ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEnvelope(-180, -90, 180, 8), 4326)) as clipped_geom
FROM polygons
WHERE ST_YMax(ST_Transform(the_web_geom, 4326)) > 8
```